# Edit cursor not displayed on Chrome in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, contenteditable

When you open this page (see [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gs3p1a6r/3/show/)) with Chrome :

```
<span id="myspan" contenteditable=true></span>
```

CSS :

```
#myspan { border: 0; outline: 0;}
```

JS :

```
$(myspan).focus();
```

the `contenteditable` `span` has focus (you can start to write things and you will see that it already had focus), but we don't see the "`I`" edit cursor.

**How to make that this cursor is displayed ?** (Remark : `outline:0` is needed, as well as the fact that the span is empty even with no white space).

*Note : With Firefox, the cursor is displayed.*

Comment: try specifying a min-width and min-height. an empty span has a rendered width and height of zero, so it can't really be moused over. by forcing it to have a size of a few pixels, there's something to mouse over.

Comment: Maybe this answer from another question might help you:
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/6249440/3298029][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6249440/3298029

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow see here: http://jsfiddle.net/gs3p1a6r/4/ or http://jsfiddle.net/gs3p1a6r/4/embedded/result/, still produces the bug. It is focused, but the cursor isn't displayed

Comment: i see, i thought you meant the mouse cursor, but you mean the blinking thing. looks like Doctus solved it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was to change `<span>` to `<div>` (I've seen that this solves many `contenteditable` problems in other questions here and there)  + to add a `min-width`.

---

Indeed, with the following code, the size of the `<div>` would be `0px x 18px` ! That explains why the *caret* (edit cursor) would be hidden !

HTML

```
<div id="blah" contenteditable=true></div>
```

CSS

```
#blah {
    outline: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
}
```

JS

```
$("#blah").focus();
```

---

Then, adding

```
min-width: 2px;
```

in the CSS **will allow the *caret* to be displayed**, even with Chrome : http://jsfiddle.net/38e9mkf4/2/

Comment: Thanks. `min-width` works fine for me. In my case, the parent of `contenteditable` element is `display: flex`, so the empty content will make the element has zero width.

Answer (score 27):

The problem is that `span`s are inline elements. Just add `display:block;` to your CSS and it will fix the problem.

```js
$(myspan).focus();
```

```css
#myspan {
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="myspan" contenteditable=true></span>
```

Comment: or maybe `display:inline-block;`

Comment: @avee `inline-block` won't fix the problem in Chrome.

Comment: that's weird, it worked fine for me in Chrome Version 51.0.2704.103 (64-bit). Maybe it's because I used Bootstrap too? Using `block` actually makes the `span` act like a `div`.

Comment: A bit more explanation: it's because inline elements collapse to `0` width with no content, whereas block elements are `100%` width by default. That is why `inline-block` elements are also affected with the same issue.

Comment: The problem isn't that `span` is `inline`, it's that `inline` elements have a width of `0` if they do not have any content. So the solution is to ensure that the element is given some width, which adding `display: block;` coincidentally does.

Answer (score 19):

I added padding to the left and the cursor appears.

```css
#myspan
{
    border: 0; 
    outline: 0; 
    min-width: 100px; 
    height: 30px; 
    padding-left: 1px;
}
```

#### [Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gs3p1a6r/7/)

Comment: Perhaps because the empty span has a width of `0`.  If the cursor needs to appear *inside* the element, then there is simply no space for it to do so unless you give it some sort of padding.  That's just a guess at least

Comment: I had another play and adding `display: block` and removing the other additions also works: http://jsfiddle.net/gs3p1a6r/10/  It would appear that inline elements with no content are not affected by `min-width`?

Answer (score 8):

```
.cont_edit {
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or turn the answer into a code snippet ? Useful for future reference. ps: I'm not the one who downvoted!

Comment: Had to use this AND display: block plus make both attributes !important because of other conflicting css on my page

Answer (score 6):

This just has to do with the way an empty `ContentEditable` area is rendered.  To prove it's not about the focus, add some text to your editable div, and then delete it.  When the last character is gone, the cursor will disappear

From the question [Setting the caret position to an empty node inside a contentEditable element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4063144/1366033)

> The selection/range model is based around indexes into text content, disregarding element boundaries. I believe it may be impossible to set the input focus inside an inline element with no text in it. Certainly with your example I cannot set focus inside the last element by clicking or arrow keys.
>
> It almost works if you set each span to `display: block`, though there's still some highly strange behaviour, dependent on the existence of whitespace in the parent. Hacking the display to look inline with tricks like float, inline-block and absolute position make IE treat each element as a separate editing box. Relative-positioned block elements next to each other work, but that's probably impractical.

---

You could also try adding a zero-width character like `&#8203;`

```js
document.getElementById('myspan').focus();
```

```css
#myspan {
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<span id="myspan" contenteditable="true">&#8203;</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue I faced on Chrome v89.0.4389.90 was that `contenteditable` fields would sometimes show the blinking caret on `focusin` and sometimes not. I noticed it always blinks when there's already content in the field before focusing. It's when there's no content that the sometimes will/won't behavior occurs.

At first, I thought there must be some conflicting event handler that's erratically taking focus away. I disabled all my event binds and timers. Still the same erratic behavior. Then I thought it might be some conflicting CSS, so I disabled all stylesheets. At least now the behavior was consistent: the caret blinks 100% of the time when the field has content; the caret does not blink 100% of the time when the field has no content.

I enabled binds and stylesheets again. My `div` was already set to `display: block;` with `min-width`, `min-height`, and `padding` set in the final computed style set. None of the other answers here worked. I do have a `placeholder` on `:empty:before` that was a possible culprit. I commented that out. Now the behavior was consistent again, same as if the stylesheet was off. Oddly enough, the runnable snippet on SO works with the same computed CSS stack. I want to keep the `placeholder`, so it requires further research with my actual codebase...

The only solution I could get to work 100% of the time with my current issue involved forcibly placing the caret inside empty fields by creating a blank space and removing it immediately afterwards. Best I can do for a workaround until debugging the root cause.

```js
//force caret to blink inside masks
let force_caret = function() {
  if (!this.textContent) {
    this.textContent = ' ';
    let r = document.createRange(),
      s = window.getSelection();
    r.setStart(this.childNodes[0], 0);
    r.collapse(true);
    s.removeAllRanges();
    s.addRange(r);
    this.textContent = '';
  }
}

//binds
let els = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable]");
for (let i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  els[i].addEventListener('focusin', force_caret, false);
}
```

```css
/* styles irrelevant to the issue, added for visual assist */

:root {
  --b-soft: 1px solid silver;
  --bs-in: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  --c-soft: gray;
  --lg-warm: linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(254, 250, 250), #eedddd);
}

body {
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, -apple-system-font, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

[contenteditable] {
  outline: initial;
}

[contenteditable][placeholder]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  color: var(--c-soft);
  background-color: transparent;
  font-style: italic;
  opacity: .5;
  font-size: .9em;
}

.input {
  border-bottom: var(--b-soft);
  padding: .2em .5em;
}

.input_mask {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  color: var(--c-soft);
}

.mask {
  box-shadow: var(--bs-in);
  border-radius: .2em;
  background: var(--lg-warm);
  font-weight: 500;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  /* styles possibly relevant to the issue according to other proposed solutions */
  margin: 0 .4em .1em .4em;
  padding: .2em .4em;
  min-width: 3em;
  min-height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div data-type="tel" data-id="phone" class="input input_mask">
  <span>+1 (</span>
  <div maxlength="3" contenteditable="true" placeholder="111" class="mask"></div>
  <span>)</span>
  <div maxlength="3" contenteditable="true" placeholder="111" class="mask"></div>
  <span>-</span>
  <div maxlength="4" contenteditable="true" placeholder="1111" class="mask"></div>
  <span>x</span>
  <div maxlength="5" contenteditable="true" class="mask"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a CSS style of

```
min-height: 15px;
```

you may also need

```
display: block;
```

to your `contenteditable="true"` tag

Answer (score 1):

For me setting it content of contenteditable div to `<br>` works. I tried setting it to `nbsp;` but that creates extra character space in the div before i start editing. So, i choose this:

```
<div id="blah" contenteditable=true><br></div>
```

over:

```
<div id="blah" contenteditable=true>nbsp;</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

I use Chrome and your Code works fine.

Try to use `cursor: text;` in your CSS. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp)

Comment: Cursor in CSS refers to the mouse cursor, which isn't necessarily in the area the span occupies. Also I use chrome and the demo doesn't work

Comment: He just want's to see the Cursor to appear. He can append it to the body when he's typing, and listen to clicks to detect when he's clicking onto another part of the Page and remove it from the body again.